# Windows 10 on Surface Pro 4 - Cannot Resize Menu Bars

Tags: windows-10, display

I have tried changing Display settings in the Display Settings screen, as well as in the Advanced settings. However, some menu bars stay very small. The example below, TreeForm, is from a jar executable, but I have a similar problem with programs like RStudio. How can I resize these menu bars?
[image]

Comment: Since what your asking must be supported by the application itself, my suggestion, is fine a tool that does

Answer (score 2):

Applications must call the new Win32 API function [EnableNonClientDpiScaling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt748621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [to scale the UI elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36864894/1466046).

> Non-client scaling for top-level windows is not enabled by default,
>   you must call this API to enable it. Once you do, there is no way to
>   disable it. **Enabling non-client scaling means that all the areas drawn
>   by the system for the window will automatically scale in response to
>   DPI changes on the window. That includes areas like the caption bar,
>   the scrollbars, and the menu bar.** You want to call
>   EnableNonClientDpiScaling when you want the operating system to be
>   responsible for rendering these areas automatically at the correct
>   size based on the API of the monitor.

Ask the developers of the tool to include this in an update.

Comment: This is the same reason many applications look weird at higher resolutions.  Apple avoids this on iOS by forcing applications to be updated to support newer versions of iOS.  Microsoft has limited control over legacy Win32 applications but more control over Universal Windows Programs.  It will take time for applications to support this newer API call, worth noting, it only works on Windows 10.  Java would also have to support dynamic dpi scaling and to my knowledge it does not or it's extremely difficult to implement currently

Comment: Unfortunately this application is no longer being actively developed. Any other possible solutions?

Comment: nope. In this case you're out of luck. HighDPi support for old Win32 desktop applications is terrible to add. I also struggle at it